# Is there a CoreText equivalent for the iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a CoreText equivalent for the iPhone SDK? I just need to draw a paragraph of text and programmatically align it to the center of the screen based on the height of the paragraph. UITextfield is overkill for this I think.

Comment: CoreText. For 4.0 onwards. And CoreText. As a private API. :)

Answer (score 2):

Core Text is available from iOS 3.2 and is including in iOS 4.0. For details, look at the [Core Text Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

I"m not sure you need core text,  you can use

```
CGSize cs = [theString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width,FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

to get the height of the paragraph. Aligning it with that info should be pretty easy.